# Canon LBP 2900B printer not working

Tags: printing

I have recently changed my PC CPU . New motherbaord is Gigabyte B550 AORUS Elite AX V2 .
i have installed ubuntu , now printer (Canon LBP 2900B) is not working with this machine.
Printer is being detected/showing on system.